# Scaling a mesh object with texture

Tags: c++, directx

I have a mesh which have a tiled texture applied. When, I scaled that object in DirectX, the size of texture tiles also gets scaled.

Is there a way to keep texture size same and scale only the object. If, object size gets increased, reapply same texture on that part again with original tile size.

Comment: Just don't scale the U,V parts of the vertices.

Comment: I didn't know how to apply transformation only on vertices and not on texture coordinates. So, I used much higher resolution texture. I was using `D3DXMESH` in DirectX 9.

Comment: @user3841111 Are we talking about DirectX9? Do we have some shaders? No? BTW, texture coordinates are never ever scaled (nor transformed in any way), at least in typical rendering situations. Dunno what's #Photon talking about. Anyway, check [Texture Addressing Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Drop, I meant exactly what you said.  Texture coordinates (usually denoted u,v) should not be scaled.  The problem description above appears to indicate that the scaling is done on the vertices directly, and not through the transformation.  In this case, a person might, by accident, multiply all values associated with a vertex, including the texture coordinates.

Comment: @Photon The interesting thing, is that (depending on what exactly user3841111 wants to achieve), "scaling" texture coordinates (i.e. pushing it's values above 1.0f) along with the wrap texture addressing mode could be the desired solution. ;) Though, for general 3D case, it is hard to figure out by which value to scale. A little bit easier for 2D case.

Comment: @Drop, perhaps, but given the question presented above, I doubt it.